# Incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSMutableArray *' with an expression of type 'NSArray *'

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

This is my code that is causing the above warning:

```
    NSMutableArray *tbValueArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:oServices1.text,
                oServices2.text,oServices3.text,oServices4.text,oServices5.text,oServices6.text,
                oServices7.text,oServices8.text,oServices9.text,oServices10.text,oServices11.text,
                oServices12.text,oServices13.text,oServices14.text,oServices15.text,oServices16.text,
                oServices17.text,oServices18.text,oServices19.text,oServices20.text,oServices21.text,
                oServices22.text,oServices23.text,oServices24.text,nil];
```

How do I change this to remove the warning?  (I have looked at Google and SO and found nothing that applies).

Comment: `NSMutableArray *tbValueArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:...` -- Do you see a conflict there??

Comment: Yes, I do now... I missed it before... did you downvote my question?

Comment: Are you complaining that someone (not me) downvoted you because you didn't stop for 10 seconds to try to actually understand the error message??

Comment: yes, I read the message, but unfortunately, it didn't make any sense to me at the time... that's why I asked.  Not everybody is as smart as you, so have some compassion, OK?

Comment: I have many times spent 15-20 minutes attempting to decipher the meaning of a single compiler or runtime message -- not debugging, just trying to understand what the message was saying.  This one was pretty clear and explicit -- it was flagging a line with the two types in it and saying you were assigning one to the other and that that was incompatible.  It could not get much clearer.

Comment: Hot Licks:  well, I guess I'm just not as smart as you are; still, that is no reason to be condescending.  I'm 71 years old, and not as sharp as I used to be, nor as fast.  Please consider that when you busting someone's chops over a simple error.  I would appreciate it. :D

Comment: OK, you've got 7 years on me.  But you're acting like you're 17.

Comment: Hot Licks:  enough!  I concede... :D  I will spend more time doing my homework before I post here...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you trying to create an NSMutableArray or an NSArray? You have declared the variable as being of type `NSMutableArray*`, but the expression on the right creates an NSArray. If you want this array to be mutable, change the receiver of `arrayWithObjects:` to be NSMutableArray; if not, change the declaration to correctly identify this as an NSArray instead of an NSMutableArray.

Comment: Chuck:  you downvoted my question; did you mean to downvote one of the answers?  This goes against me, and I would appreciate it if you would contact the moderator and get it reversed.  SD

Comment: @spokane-dude - Dude, complaining about downvotes is a sure-fire way to get downvoted.

Comment: @spokane-dude: I don't know what gave you the impression that I downvoted your question. You can't see who downvotes you. In this case, it wasn't me.

Comment: @spokane-dude: Please stop accusing people of downvoting you. *Especially* the ones that are giving you the right answer. (And voting is anonymous besides.)

Comment: Chuck:  I apologize...

Answer (score 2):

You can't cast an NSArray as an NSMutableArray. Just initialize it as an NSMutableArray

```
NSMutableArray *tbValueArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: ... ]
```

Alternatively, if you don't actually need an NSMutableArray, change your variable type to NSArray*

```
NSArray *tbValueArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: ... ]
```

Comment: Don't understand why somebody give you -1. Same answer and nice answer +1

Comment: @JordanMontel: I downvoted when he first posted it because at that point the answer was literally just `NSArray *tbValueArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: ... ]` with no further commentary. I would remove the downvote now that it's a real answer, but for some reason Stack Overflow will not let me.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
NSMutableArray *tbValueArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:...];
```

by

```
NSArray *tbValueArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:...];
```